# Importing Localizations in Xcode zh-Hans inserts line above and below each string

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xliff

When I `Import Localizations` in Xcode each string inserts a line above and below the actual translation. Other languages work fine. The zh-Hans xliff file does not have the line above and below the translated strings.

Here is the plain text in the zh.xliff file:

[image]

Here is the translation in my project in a .strings file:

[image]

This is the case for every single string in the whole xliff.

(This is the first ever import for Chinese. The other languages have been there a while.)